# Best way to go about removing middle element from list or arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, data-structures

I need sequentially remove the middle element from sorted data. What would be the best way to do that? Since LinkedList operation takes n/2 time to remove the element, an arraylist would be faster. But an arraylist on the other hand then takes time to shift all the elements to the left, which isn't efficient either. Would other datastructures be of use maybe?

Comment: What other kinds of operations do you need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the middle element is composed of two parts:

1. Finding the middle element
2. Deleting that element

`ArrayList` is `O(1)` at random access, so *1st* step is fast for Array. While `LinkedList` is `O(1)` at deletion (given node), so *2nd* step is easy for List.

What you want is *best of both worlds*.

**IMO** this is easily achievable if you **write a custom (or extend existing) LinkedList**. You'll need to have extra `middle` reference variable which will :

- move to `next` upon insertion if the size becomes odd.
- move to `prev` upon deletion if the size becomes odd.

You can also do even in both cases but they must be same (either even or odd).

Answer (score 0):

Might a `TreeSet` fit the bill? If offers removal in O(log n) by key.